# How to install Oracle extensions for PHP on Linux SUSE?

Tags: linux, oracle, sles

does anyone have some experience in installing the ORACLE PHP extensions (oci_connect()) on Linux SUSE ?

Thank you
Antonio

Answer (score 2):

I did so on SLES 10 and 11 by downloading and adding the SLES SDK to the package-repositories and installing `php5-devel`. Then you need to download and install the [Oracle Instant Client](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/instant-client/index-097480.html) RPMs (oracle-instantclient11.2-devel and oracle-instantclient11.2-basic).

Next create a file `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/oracle.conf` with the content (assuming you are on x86_64):

```
/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64/lib/
```

This will allow you to load the Oracle libraries from within PHP later on.

Now install the OCI extension by calling `pecl install oci8`. If asked for the path to the Oracle Instant Client libraries just confirm the default value. if this does not work try to provide `/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64` as the path.

once installation of `oci8` has finished make sure that it's loaded by creating the file `/etc/php5/conf.d/oci.ini` with this content:

```
extension=oci8.so
```

I assume you are using PHP inside Apache so you will have to restart Apache for mod_php5 to load the `oci8.so` module. Check with `phpinfo()` that the module was loaded correctly.

Comment: I'm stuck at the first point :( is there a way to add SLES SDK without having to download and burn the ISO ?

Comment: You can add it as a ISO source in YaST or you can download and mount the ISO: `mkdir -p /mnt/sdk/ && mount -o loop /path/to/sdk.iso /mnt/sdk`
And then add `/mnt/sdk` as a installation source in YaST. Or you can cherry-pick all the rpms from the ISO and upload the to the machine to install them manually using `rpm`.

Answer (score 2):

I also seemed to have had to run ldconfig afterward, then restart apache for oci8 to show up in phpinfo (sles 11 64, php 5.2, apache2)